# Sql in DB2.... DISTINCT

Tags: sql

In DB2, I want to display 2 columns' values that match each other and also distinct leaving behind duplicate values. 
Eg:- Employee_name and Employee_salary both should display distinct values and the salary value shown should be the one for its corresponding employee value

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question with more relevant information, like your table structure, what kind of data does it store an example set of data  (don't need to be real just few lines) and from that sample example the desired result. **And most important** add the code you have tried. We are not here to do your work we help to solve problems in existing code.

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic SQL and we can't really answer because you don't tell us anything about your data model.  It could be

```
 SELECT name, salary FROM employee
```

I doubt

```
 SELECT distinct name, salary FROM employee
```

would be needed because, well you would only have one record per employee.

It could also be more complicated.  For example it could be

```
select e.name, s.value 
from employee e
join salary s on e.id = s.employee_id
```

It could also be more complicated than this... like if the salary table contained the history of a given employee's salary.

Basically there is no way to know the answer to your question unless you tell us about the data model.

Comment: the syntax you have given works for me. No worries, I have another query in DB2. The date field in my table is in the format Feb 23, 2011. Now I want to bring out historical data for past 5 years from 2011 to 2015. How can I write it ?

Comment: I've no idea what you are talking about

Comment: I want all of table data ( select *) .....using where clause and give the condition of date range from the year 2011 to 2015. I tried using LIKE (LIKE '%2011') .......and so on but I have to keep typing in the column and LIKE using 'OR'

Comment: Here it is, Select * from "FT_ORDERS" 
WHERE DATE_LSO_RECV LIKE '2011%' 
OR DATE_LSO_RECV LIKE '2012%'
OR DATE_LSO_RECV LIKE '2015%'..... This gives the Results Im looking for but I need more simpler syntax to avoid typing in 'OR' operator. Do you know of any syntax like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use group by to remove the duplicate record.

SELECT Employee_name , Employee_salary FROM Employee GROUP BY Employee_name , Employee_salary.

This SQL will consider Employee_name+Employee_salary is a unique key. And remove all the duplicate record.
For example:
John 10000
Peter 4000
John 10000
Setven 30000
John 3000
The result are 
John 10000
Peter 4000
Setven 30000
John 3000

John 10000 have been removed. If you want to remove duplicate record base off Employee_name. You can use group Employee_name instead.